# IIS + TOMCAT - uriworkermap.properties config

Tags: iis, tomcat, isapi

Trying to find the best way to setup the uriworkermap.properties file on IIS. We are using this:

```
/*=worker
```

With that line we can reach any new apps that are deployed to Tomcat without having to edit the properties file each time. The only issue with this method is that I can't seem to set an exclusion for any static files we might want IIS to handle. Is there a way to make this setup work?

The goal is to make deploying apps as simple as possible in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I had an old version of the isapi_redirect.dll installed. Installed the new one and this worked. In case someone stumbles on this question -  the properties file works with:

```
/*=worker
!/includes/*=worker
```

So Tomcat ignores any request for the /includes URI and IIS can pick it up.

I got the latest isapi_redirect.dll file here:
[Tomcat Connectors](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-connectors.cgi)